# Proving inequalities hold when applying exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, real-numbers

So I'm set out to prove that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ where $a,b > 0$, and for all $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ where $r > 0$,

$$
a < b \quad \text{if and only if} \quad a^r<b^r
$$

This seems so obvious that it shouldn't have to be proved, and thus I'm not really sure how to start.

Comment: Hint: $\ln{x}$ is a strictly increasing function, so if $a < b$, $\ln{a} < \ln{b}$.

Comment: First prove the problem for $a=1$ and then note that the problem can be reduced to this special case by dividing the inequality by $a^r$.

Comment: What is your defintion of $a^r$?

Answer (score 4):

The hint:
$$b^r-a^r=a^r\left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^r-1\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

A strategy can be like this:

1. prove that it holds for $r\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$;
2. use (1) to prove that it holds when $\frac1r\in\Bbb N$;
3. use (1) and (2) to prove that it holds for all $r\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$.